# first character count navigation with Oracle: count queries dont't use functional indices

Tags: oracle, indexing

Oracle 9i. We have a large table (~1M rows) containing our content that carries title and author columns. We'd like to write views that offer an A-Z navigation for titles and authors to that content ( A:1300, B:45000,...)

First some preparation without any indexing:

```
select * from content where substr(upper(title),0,1) = 'M'
```

performs a little better than

```
select * from content where upper(title) LIKE 'M%'
```

ExPlan for those:

```
TABLE ACCESS content FULL Cost=1624
```

both are pretty fast even without any indices. Now the slow part:

```
select count(*) from CONTENT WHERE substr(upper(TITLE),0,1) = 'A';
```

ExPlan:

```
SORT AGGREGATE else like above.
```

Now the cumulation (this is what we want, it's really slow):

```
select substr(upper(title),0,1) , count(*) from content group by substr(upper(title),0,1);
```

ExPlan:

```
SORT: GROUP BY COST=8069 / TABLE ACCESS on CONTENT FULL COST=1624
```

So I started creating a functional index:

```
create index CONTENT_TITLE_LETTER_IDX on CONTENT(substr(upper(TITLE),0,1));
```

This speeds up the single letter count query dramatically:

```
select count(*) from CONTENT WHERE substr(upper(TITLE),0,1) = 'A';
```

ExPlan (it responds nearly in realtime):

```
SORT AGGREGATE COST=1 / INDEX CONTENT_TITLE_LETTER_IDX RANGE SCAN COST=1
```

But the cumulation query which is basically querying the same thing is not using the index (it shows the same Explain Plan as above). I tried the hint:

```
select /*+ index(CONTENT CONTENT_TITLE_LETTER_IDX) */ substr(upper(title),0,1) , count(*) from content group by substr(upper(title),0,1);
```

but it still is very slow. I assume that this might be due to the unordered index but I'd guess that even if I ran a loop around all 26 possible letters the single query ( = 'letter' ) would be faster!

Who knows how to tell Oracle to use that index (or an alternative way besides creating one-char columns or tables) ?

Answer (score 3):

Take another look at your query:

```
select substr(upper(title),0,1) , count(*) 
from content 
group by substr(upper(title),0,1)
```

Note the absence of any `where` clause. In fact, you tell the database engine to take *all* rows and count how many rows there is for each initial letter. You cannot skip any row because else you can't count it. I don't think the index stores such information readily, so a full scan is the fastest you can have. If you asked for a specific letter, using a range scan on the index could make sense.

If you need this information often, create a summary table which would be updated by triggers on your main table.

Comment: +1 but since this is Oracle, I'd much rather see a fast-refreshable materialized view to maintain the summary table.

Comment: @Justin-Cave: Plain MV would issue the same full-scan queries, I suppose. Since updates are probably not very frequent this won't be much of an issue, but the view will lag behind a bit. Triggers would refresh the view immediately and cheaply.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this answers the question but doesn't really solve the problem (thanks Gerrat, we're nearly same time):

I had a look at [this interesting question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736878/how-can-i-get-a-countcol-group-by-to-use-an-index) that told me that the CBO might reject indices containing NULL values. Taking into account that our table contains title that start with non-alpha characters and blanks (but never are null...) I tried the following:

```
select   substr(upper(title),0,1), count(*) 
from content
 where substr(upper(title),0,1) >= 'A' AND substr(upper(title),0,1) <= 'Z'
group by substr(upper(title),0,1);
```

which dramatically decreases the costs:

```
SORT GROUP BY NOSORT COST=16 / CONTENT ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID COST=6 / CONTENT_TITLE_LETTER_IDX RANGE SCAN COST=2
```

from 8069 to 16

interestingly that conditioned query now even is **slower** (avg 2.7s) than the non-conditioned one (avg 1.5s). Adding more conditions as stated by 9000 dramatically speeds things up - even though it doesn't use the letter index at all. Thanks for that
insight!

Comment: +1, you've found the main cause of the index not being used. Altough I would prefer the clause `WHERE substr(upper(TITLE),0,1) IS NOT NULL` which should produce the same plan and will be (IMO) more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I can't promise you this will be faster, but you could try:

```
select /*+ index(CONTENT CONTENT_TITLE_LETTER_IDX) */ substr(upper(title),0,1), 
count(*) from content 
where substr(upper(title),0,1) in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 
'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 
'X', 'Y', 'Z')
group by substr(upper(title),0,1);
```

On a similar test I did, this did use the index (nothing else I tried did), but the cost was actually higher than the full table scan).

Make sure your table and index are analyzed as well.

Comment: This opens another can of worms if a title begins with a '1' or 'É' or 'Я', etc. Can't bet it would be any faster than a full scan, though.